# how to link a static library for iOS

Tags: ios, gcc, build, static-libraries, ld

I have create a bunch of `.o` files (via `gcc -c $file.c $someotherops -o $file.o`). Now I want to link them into a static library.

I'm not exactly sure wether I am supposed to use `ld` or `gcc` for this. In the `ld` manual, it is said that I'm not supposed to use it directly. However, I cannot figure out the gcc parameters to create a static library.

I tried `ld *.o -static -o libfoo.a` but it complains about a lot of missing symbols (I think all from libc). I don't understand why it complains because it is supposed to be a static library. I thought it would check for the symbols once I link that static library to some other thing.

Another thing: I use `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ld` here (my target is iOS). It complains with the warning `ld: warning: using ld_classic`. What is this about?

Then I thought, maybe it needs to have the dynamic libraries specified. So I added `-lc` to link against libc. But it complains with `can't locate file for: -lc`. I added `-L/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/lib` and there is a `libc.dylib`.

Any ideas?

---

About the `-lc` error: It got away after I specified `-arch armv6`. Then it complained about a wrong `libcache.dylib` (which must be linked from `libc.dylib` I guess because it didn't specified it). Adding `-L.../usr/lib/system` helped.

Now, for each single `.o` file, I get the warning `ld: warning: CPU_SUBTYPE_ARM_ALL subtype is deprecated`. What is this about?

And I still have a bunch of missing symbols, esp:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv6:
  "start", referenced from:
     -u command line option
     (maybe you meant: _PyThread_start_new_thread)
  "___udivsi3", referenced from:
      _get_len_of_range in bltinmodule.o
      _quorem in dtoa.o
      _array_resize in arraymodule.o
      _newarrayobject in arraymodule.o
      _array_fromfile in arraymodule.o
      _get_len_of_range in rangeobject.o
      _inplace_divrem1 in longobject.o
      ...
  "___unorddf2", referenced from:
      _builtin_round in bltinmodule.o
  ...
```

I checked some of those symbols, e.g. `___udivsi3` in `get_len_of_range`. This function uses C arithmetic only, no external call. So this seems to be translated to use some external functions like `___udivsi3`. But what libraries is this in?

---

`-lgcc_s.1` fixed most of the `___udivsi3` and related missing symbols. The `start` symbol is still missing. What does `-u command line option` mean?

---

From [here](http://codingfreak.blogspot.de/2010/01/creating-and-using-static-libraries-in.html), I got the feeling that maybe `ld` isn't the right tool after all. There, a simple call to `ar`is used. And this seem to make more sense. I will check if that does work and transform this into an answer then.

---

While playing more around, `ar` throw some warnings at me when building a fat static library. It gave me the hint to use `libtool` instead. That is what I'm doing now, i.e. `libtool -static -o libfoo.a *.o`. Also I switched the compiler to `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang`but not sure if that matters.

Now, at compiling some test application which links to this static library, I get these warnings:

```
ld: warning: PIE disabled. Absolute addressing (perhaps -mdynamic-no-pic) not allowed in code signed PIE, but used in __PyBuiltin_Init from /Users/az/Programmierung/python-embedded/libpython.a(bltinmodule.o). To fix this warning, don't compile with -mdynamic-no-pic or link with -Wl,-no_pie
ld: warning: 32-bit absolute address out of range (0x1001B70C4 max is 4GB): from _usedpools + 0x00000004 (0x001B70CC) to 0x1001B70C4
ld: warning: 32-bit absolute address out of range (0x1001B70C4 max is 4GB): from _usedpools + 0x00000000 (0x001B70CC) to 0x1001B70C4
```

What are they about? I don't use `-mdynamic-no-pic`. I also don't really see in `_PyBuiltin_Init` how I use absolute addressing there.

Also, what are these absolute addresses out of range about? **Edit:** These were some really huge allocations. I just removed this code for now (this was `WITH_PYMALLOC`, if anyone is interested in these specific Python internals).

When I start it on my iPhone, I get the abort:

`dyld: vm_protect(0x00001000, 0x00173000, false, 0x07) failed, result=2 for segment __TEXT in /var/mobile/Applications/C15D9525-E7DC-4463-B05B-D39C9CA24319/...`

When I use `-no_pie` for linking, it doesn't even link. It fails with:

`Illegal text-relocation to ___stderrp in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.dylib from _read_object in /Users/az/Programmierung/python-embedded/libpython.a(marshal.o) for architecture armv7`

---

I solved the PIE disabled, Absolute addressing error. I had a `-static` in my command line Clang. Once I removed that, the warning got away, as well as the dyld/vm_protect error. It was the first time it actually run some code.

Until I hit [another strange error about integer comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11129368/strange-c-integer-inequality-comparison-result). Whereby this looks more like a bug in their Clang build.

Comment: one question; why you don't create a XCoe Static Library Project and build you Static Library with that project?

Comment: @meccan: I want to have my own compile script in this case for varios reasons (mostly because for this particular project, this is much simpler now). Anyway, even if I would do it with Xcode, this question stays valid/open as I want to understand how to do it manually.

Comment: okay, and you know you can build a Xcode project from the shell?

Comment: Yes sure. But it would be almost impossible or at least be very annoying to have an Xcode project here (and to update/maintain it). Also, I don't really see the reason to have it in the first place. It's this project: [python-embedded](https://github.com/albertz/python-embedded/). Whereby I want to know this in any case for maybe other future use and just to understand better how it works.

Comment: http://mark.aufflick.com/blog/2010/11/18/making-a-fat-static-library-for-ios-device-and-simulator did you checked this site?

Comment: @meccan: That doesn't help because it needs a Xcode project and uses `xcodebuild`.

Comment: Why use Xcode? Because (a) it's the platform norm, (b) it's simpler, and (c) you wouldn't need to ask this.

Comment: @StevenFisher: My question is not necessarily even iPhone/iOS specific. Also, I still want to know, wether using Xcode or not. Also, Xcode is not an option in this case. Also, I guess I would even get the same error in Xcode.

Comment: I think it's great to know how to do things like this, but were you using Xcode you wouldn't even be using `gcc` as a compiler. It's not Xcode's standard compiler, and isn't even going to be included in the future. It's too bad using Xcode isn't an option for you, because as a result you're going to be cutting against the grain. Cutting with the grain is really important in software development.

Comment: Xcode isn't doing anything special. It's just a wrapper around GCC/Clang/libtool/ar/ld and other tools. The recent versions use Clang by default. Really, I just do the same as what Xcode would do. (I just checked. I created a static lib in Xcode and looked at the clang/libtool commands which are executed by Xcode.) Also, you are very much limiting yourself if you don't know this stuff. Also, Xcode is not an option for cross platform development.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It all works now. Basically, the answer is:

- Just compile every `*.c` file as usual to `*.o` files. The only real difference is the different GCC/Clang, the `-arch armv7`, the different SDK / include dirs.
- Use `libtool -static -o libfoo.a *.o` to build the static library.

That's it. The other problems in my question were just wrongly headed tries.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone gets here by searching for the `dyld: vm_protect(...)` runtime error but you are using XCode, the `-static` flag mentioned in the OP is likely the issue.

Get rid of it by switching "Enable linking with shared libraries" to "Yes" (the default) in the LLVM compiler language settings. (This removes `GCC_LINK_WITH_DYNAMIC_LIBRARIES = NO` from the project file).