# Statically link OpenSSL in XCode

Tags: xcode, openssl, static-linking, dylib

I am trying to link `libssl.a` and `libcrypto.a` static libraries in XCode command line project [under Link Binary With Libraries]. I have included Openssl header files in search path.

Compilation succeeds but execution fails with *`dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib`*.

Why does it look for dylib when I am linking it statically? How can this be fixed?

Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: Anil - is this iOS, OS X or both?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Why does it look for dylib when I am linking it statically? How can this be fixed?

Apple's linker uses the dylib or share object if its available, regardless of of your linker flags like `-rpath` and `-Bstatic`. They even do it on iOS, where dylib's are not allowed!

Its kind of a well known problem once you know about it :) See, for example, [Installing Crypto++ 5.6.2 on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25733194/608639). Crypto++ has the same problems with Apple's tools.

The fix is to *stop* using `-L` and `-l` options, and to link the object file or archive directly. An archive is just a collection of object files, so you can use them interchangeably.

To specify the object files or archives for the linker, see [Linking to an object file](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/xcode/264949-linking-to-an-object-file.html). Under Xcode, you add the fully specified archive name (like `/usr/local/openssl-ios/lib/libcrypto.a`) to ***Other Linker Flags*** (the [`OTHER_LDFLAGS`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html) Xcode option).

When adding the full archive to `OTHER_LDFLAGS`, I believe you just add it verbatim ***without*** any switches, like `-l` or `-L`. You *may* need `-Wl` (`-Wl,/usr/local/openssl-ios/lib/libcrypto.a`), but you ***don't*** use `-l` (`-l/usr/local/openssl-ios/lib/libcrypto.a`).

You use `-Wl` when the option is passed through the compiler driver to the linker. If the linker is invoked directly, then you don't need `-Wl` and should not use it.

---

A second option is to set `GCC_LINK_WITH_DYNAMIC_LIBRARIES` to `YES`. Apple does not appear to document it in [Xcode Build Setting Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html), but its clearly under my copy of Xcode. See [How to link a static library for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11064984/608639) on Stack Overflow.

I seem to recall having problems with this in the past. Its one of those things that should work in theory, but does not work in practice.

---

A third option is to remove the dylib or shared object from all paths used under Xcode so Xcode does not accidentally find it when using `-lcrypto`.

---

A fourth option is use allow dynamic linking, but execute the program with [`DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dyld.1.html). Its OS X's equivalent to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, and ensures your copy of OpenSSL is loaded (like 1.0.2), and not the system's version of OpenSSL (0.9.8).

But I don't like this option because it requires users of your software to do something.

---

Another possibility due to the message *`dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib`* is to code sign your copy of the library. Its a little odd its found but not loaded, so I'm going to toss this out there in case its OS X's [Code Signing](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) or [Gatekeeper Service](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202491)...

To code sign your copy of the library under the MAC Developer program, just:

```
codesign -fs "Johnny Developer" /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.so
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. 1) It works if i use -Wl,$path_to_lib.a in OTHER_LINKER_FLAGS even if I remove the libraries from "Link Binary With Library". How is it even possible? I hope the openssl preinstalled on MAC does not interfere? 2) Is openssl installed on MAC-OSX always by default? If it is would it make a difference if we use it directly (using NSTask) without going into the complication of statically or dynamically linking.

Comment: It is picking up the right version. I have built the static library version 1.0.2a and the output of  SSLeay_version is 1.0.2a 19 Mar. Also does it make sense if openssl is preinstalled always then we can directly call openssl functions through NSTask without linking it with a project?

Comment: *"1.0.2a 19 Mar"* - 1.0.2c is the latest, and it has security bug fixes. *"Does it make sense if openssl is preinstalled..."* - Apple's version of OpenSSL is 0.9.8. It lacks most EC support, TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2 (among others). You should probably avoid it.

Comment: *"How is it even possible?"* - oh, my bad... Yes, that works. It works because your are specifying object files for the linker to link to. An archive is just a collection of object files. Even though you use that trick, be sure you use `-I...` to specify the header files for that particular library.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem after upgrading from Xcode 9 to Xcode 10. My iOS app builds and launches, but I get a dyld error on launch of openssl.framework `image not found`... ?? I should mention that the upgrade of Xcode 10 (Swift 4.2) required a `pod repo update` and `pod install`.